# Add AVPlayerLayer to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Is it possible to display `AVPlayerLayer` inside a `UIViewController` which is later on displayed in `UIView`.

The sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
...
UIView *parentView = reinterpret_cast<UIView *>(window->winId());

AVPlayer *_player;
AVURLAsset *_asset;
AVPlayerItem *_playerItem;
AVPlayerLayer *m_playerLayer;
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
_asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:baseURL];
_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: _asset];
[_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
m_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];

// works with AVPlayerViewController
// AVPlayerViewController *playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
// playerController.player = _player;

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController.view.layer addSublayer:m_playerLayer];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height());
[parentView addSubview:viewController.view];

[_player play];
...
```

It works if I try to add the player to `AVPlayerViewController` and then display it, but I would want to use only AVPlayerLayer since I don't need video controls as I'll implement the functionality separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVPlayerViewController` with

```
avController.showsPlaybackControls = false;
```

---

Or simply add the layer

```
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
_asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:baseURL];
_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: _asset];
[_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
m_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
m_playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:m_playerLayer ]; 
[_player play];
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `AVPlayerViewController`, but that's the last option if displaying `AVPlayerLayer` is not possible.

Comment: it's a usual layer you can add it to `self.view.layer`

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed UIView and added on the AVPlayerLayer via SH_Khans method

```
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
_asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:baseURL];
_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: _asset];
[_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
m_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
m_playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:m_playerLayer ]; 
[_player play];
```

Then treat the subclassed UIView how you want. Couple of things though, if you resize the AVPlayerLayerUIView you have to resize the AVPlayerLayer as the system does not do that automatically.
Additionally remember to clip to bounds on the AVPlayerLayerUIView or it will not match your frame as you want.